# Unable to remove view from superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using banner code, to show the banner in the below example code

```
   HZBannerAdOptions *options = [[HZBannerAdOptions alloc] init];
        [HZBannerAd requestBannerWithOptions:options success:^(HZBannerAd *banner) {
            [viewController.view addSubview:banner];
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
        }];
```

However, when I want to hide/remove the banner, I use this;

```
[self.currentBannerAd removeFromSuperview];
    self.currentBannerAd = nil;
```

But it is not working, the banner is still there, I have tried some variants such as

```
[currentBannerAd setHidden:YES];
```

With no success, any ideas how to remove this banner from the view?

Comment: Show the code where you add `self.currentBannerAd` as subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the banner to the view, you have no reference to it, you have to assign it to a property like this:

```
HZBannerAdOptions *options = [[HZBannerAdOptions alloc] init];
[HZBannerAd requestBannerWithOptions:options success:^(HZBannerAd *banner) {
    self.currentBannerAd = banner;
    [viewController.view addSubview:self.currentBannerAd];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
}];
```

And then remove it using your own code, just add the layoutIfNeeded line:

```
[self.currentBannerAd removeFromSuperview];
self.currentBannerAd = nil;
[viewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Forgot to add the `layoutIfNeeded`, this will force to relayout the view's subviews